# Spark DataFrame courses

Tags: apache-spark, education, pyspark

If I understand the Databricks philosophy correctly, Spark will soon be heavily moving toward dataframes, i.e. away from the usual map/reduce on RDDs. I was wondering if there are any good suggestions for online courses or books that introduce Spark from the dataframe point of view? I know Databricks has a good number of resources on dataframes but I would really like to see some more detailed courses.

Answer (score 1):

edX offers some spark courses. Try the following:

https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-apache-spark-uc-berkeleyx-cs105x?gclid=CjwKEAjwm8-6BRDgnb-Dk96UmRASJADbMycYmMKC3xWs_3jGV9pUd0k3gxIbQRHE2H4_hlXeNMw1BhoCqHjw_wcB

I believe this is through a partnership with Databricks

Comment: I know of the old version of this course which is still using the old paradigm. Maybe the next one is new?

Answer (score 0):

Alex, you can check in this Coursera Big Data Course a chapter about Spark DataFrames in "Week 5", it's an introduction but it explains how to setup PySpark for DataFrames, may be for your situation it would be a good start.

[Big Data Analytics](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bigdata-analytics)

Regards

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore. Might be helpful to note which institution offered it and who the instructor was, to help narrow it down within the Coursera search results.

Comment: Hi Brian, the Coursera Specialization has changed a few months ago, now you can access trough the Big Data Specialization from UC San Diego in the third course, but is a simple introduction with a initial tutorial for start to know Spark https://www.coursera.org/specializations/big-data . Also you have the Edx Course mentioned in other answer that is a part of spark series https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-apache-spark-uc-berkeleyx-cs105x